# Execute query once in SQL Server despite being called mutiple times

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

I have a situation where a query might be called multiple times from multiple users, but I only want it to run once (per week) against the database. The environment is SQL Server Express so scheduling via SQL Server Agent is not an option. It needs to be 2005 compatible. I'd like to make it as lightweight as possible too, so I'm asking for suggestions. Ideally a database wide declared variable - but I don't think that SQL Server supports such a beast? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
IF NOT EXISTS ( -- Check if you have the current week content
    SELECT  * 
    FROM    WeeklyTable 
    WHERE 
            DATEPART(YEAR, DateCr) = DATEPART(YEAR, GETDATE())
            AND
            DATEPART(WEEK, DateCr) = DATEPART(WEEK, GETDATE())
  )
BEGIN 
   -- delete old content
  DELETE WeeklyTable
   -- insert new content
  INSERT INTO WeeklyTable (MyID, MyField1, ... , MyFieldN, DateCr)
    SELECT 
      MyID, MyField1, MyField2, GETDATE()
    FROM MainTable
END
```

You can create indexes you need for the WeeklyTable.

Comment: Thanks, that would certainly work, for some reason I was tackling the problem from another direction.

Comment: The full solution involved creating a Service broker "thread" which can be configuered to have only one active message.

Answer (score 1):

One option would be [SQL Scheduler](http://www.lazycoding.com/products.aspx) as a add-on to SQL Server Express.

The other option would be to create a small command-line utility that does the querying and schedule that using the Windows Scheduler on the machine where SQL Server Express is installed.

With either of the two setups, you could select the values / numbers you need into a result table once a week, and any requests during the week would be satisfied from that one result table. SQL Server doesn't have "server-wide" variables - but you can always define a table for that purpose...

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I'm aiming for an (ideal) solution that doesnt require any addtional add ins that the basic sql express install doesnt have. I just think there must be sufficient functionality within sQL its self, but I dont want it to hog resources. I will invesigate SQL sheduler though